# Change the order of test method execution in Maven (Junit) dynamically

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am looking for a way to change the order in which the test **methods** are executed inside of a test class using commandline. Three important remarks:

1. Yes, I am fully aware of issues about test order execution, and that running tests in a fixed order may cause dependency between tests, I am aware of mocking techniques, tear down methods etc. However, I am doing a research where doing this is necessary, I am **not** developing software.
2. I am looking for a way to change the order of test **methods** NOT **classes**.
3. I am looking for a way to dynamically induce this, meaning something like @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.Alphanumeric.class) would not be ideal. Being able to change the order through commandline arguments would be ideal.

Comment: You can explicit give the test on command line...but dynamically changing the order not that I know.. the question is why should this being done? Apart from that JUnit Jupiter changes the order of test...

Comment: @khmarbaise The reason is academic research on dependency between tests and no running a single test is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You can give several tests in one go...`-Dtest=T1,T2,T3` or more or you can use the order property via https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder ?

Comment: Write your own MethodOrderer?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen are MethodOrderers available for both Junit5 and Junit4?

Comment: At least for jUnit 5.  How experienced a programmer are you?